# Parsing the result on an API, formatting it and adding it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, api

If I wanted to get a response from this api (https://api.raisely.com/v3/campaigns/c77760a0-a4ca-11ea-a5a7-472c2e3c3966?private=false)

and create a variable for the `display_total` data in the response,

But I want to remove the last two digits of the "display_total" data and put commas in. to separate thousands, hundreds of thousands and millions

which I could then use in a HTML tag such as  how would I do it?

Below is where it will be displayed

[image]

Comment: Could you edit this question and add your code?

Comment: Edited the question a bit to remove irrelevant information. To get a good answer and not get your question closed, you should really consider sharing what you've tried so far. If you are completely new to programming and have no idea what to do, a Javascript tutorial might be better. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: In short: if you have code.. share what you tried and share what you got stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example with Jquery: https://codepen.io/ron7/pen/MWKWRrB

```js
$.getJSON( "https://api.raisely.com/v3/campaigns/c77760a0-a4ca-11ea-a5a7-472c2e3c3966?private=false", function( data ) {
let n="" + data.data.totals[0].display_total;
 n = n.slice(0, -2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
 $('.amount').text(n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount: <span class='amount'></span>
```

Comment: That is really helpful thankyou, and how would I go about putting commas between the thousands

Comment: you are my hero